# Why is PHP header() returning unexpected value?

Tags: php

Below is a method from my Router class. The class routes requests to a callback function that is user defined. The issue I am having is the header returns the $status of 404 even though $status is set to 200 in the conditional within the foreach loop. I have echo'd out the $status and it confirms that it is set to 200. Although, if I set the value of $status to 200 in the declaration of it, it works fine.

```
public function run()
{
    $current_route = null;
    $routes        = null;
    $status        = 404; // http status code

    if ($this->request_method == 'GET') {
        $routes = $this->get_routes;
    }

    foreach ($routes as $route) {
        if ($route['path'] == $this->url_path) {
            $status = 200;
            $current_route = $route;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ($status == 200) {
        header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 200 OK");
        call_user_func($current_route['callback'], $this->app);
        exit();
    } else {
        header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 404 Not Found");
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: As a note, call_user_func() is being executed as expected.

Comment: echo $status after the foreach, then you'l see if the value was manipulated in the loop

Comment: To be sure, the `$status` is 200 since you say the `call_user_func` is executed right?

Comment: It echos 200 so it indeed was manipulated

Comment: @Perry That is correct

Comment: I'm using curl --head to get the headers. Could it be something with curl?

Comment: Any possibility `$_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]` could have a somewhat unexpected value? Maybe php / apache falls back to a default header. Also try `printf "GET /<url> HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: <host>\r\nConnection: Close\r\n\r\n" | nc <ip> 80` and see what the raw headers are like.

Comment: @milkcup are you using curl cli or with php?

Comment: @Perry I am using cli.

Comment: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Wed, 19 Oct 2016 12:17:33 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Unix) PHP/7.0.11
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.11
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Comment: If I change $status to 200 in the declaration of it, the header status is 200 OK. So it's pretty strange.